# Why doesn't the underscore work here?

Tags: scala

New to scala and wondering why the underscore doesn't work on the last line below, whereas the 'for' loop syntax at line 3 works fine. BTW Leaf is a case class and can accept (Char, Int) to apply/construct.
Thanks!

```
  val chars: (List[Char]) = List('a', 'b')
  var leaves: ListBuffer[Leaf] = ListBuffer()

  for (c <- chars) leaves.append(Leaf(c, 1))//ok
  leaves.foreach(leaves.append(Leaf(_, 1)))//COMPILE ERROR
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and add the definition of `Leaf` and the *exact* error message you get.

Answer (score 3):

The rules of `_` notation are such that `Leaf(_, 1)` is equivalent to `x => Leaf(x, 1)`, so `leaves.foreach(leaves.append(Leaf(_, 1)))` is equivalent to `leaves.foreach(leaves.append(x => Leaf(x, 1)))`. This is an error because `leaves.append` doesn't take a function and also because `foreach` does.

What you want is `leaves.foreach(x => leaves.append(Leaf(x, 1)))`, which gives `foreach` a function. However I'd expect that this still would not work as `x` would have type `Leaf` and I'd expect that you can't wrap a leaf around another leaf.